# Using VB2010 to view an Excel 2003 chart

Tags: office-interop, excel-2003, vb.net-2010

I am trying to take a chart(on it's own "sheet", not as an object inside of another "sheet"), and display it on a VB2010 windows form.

The only thing I could find was creating the chart using code, and then loading in the data series from excel.  ie. Chart1.ChartType = "XYscatter" or something along those lines, and I haven't even gotten that to work right.

I have way to many charts to go through and manually set them to the way they should be.  Is there an easy way to just use Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop to do something along the lines of

```
Chart1 = xlWorkBook.Charts("MyChart")
```

?

Comment: A different approach may be of interest: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/8fa3531a-4315-4fb9-882f-8d24999db9c3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are on the right line, if you have specific questions about creating a chart with code, post what you've got and i'll see if i can help

If you want to display the chart on a .Net form it might be best to take an image of the chart and put that on the form

get a chart object:

```
Set Chart1 = xlWorkBook.Charts("MyChart")
```

copy it

```
Chart1.ChartArea.Copy
```

its now on the clipboard.  you should be able to access from there in .Net as you see fit

To prove its there, you can paste it into a normal excel worksheet

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", _
    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```